# Qt QTreeWidget add items one by one

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

this is my code

```
QList<QString> IPs;  //IP address
...
connect(this, SIGNAL(addItems(QTreeWidgetItem*)), this, 
              SLOT(addNewItemToTree(QTreeWidgetItem*)));

void MainWindow::startPing()
{        
    for (int i = ipStart; i <= ipEnd; i++)
    {           
        QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        item->setText(0, IPs.at(i));
        if (PingHost(IPs.at(i)))
        {
            item->setText(1, "online");

        }
        else
        {
            item->setText(1, "offline");
        }
        emit addItems(item);
    }
}

void MainWindow::addNewItemToTree(QTreeWidgetItem *item)
{
    items.append(item);
    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);
}
```

`PingHost` is a function, It's run time maybe over 2 second.

I compiled and run this program whitout any error or warning.

I think `item` will be added to `treeWidget` one by one (one item is been added, after 2 second, another one will be added.)

but, when I run it, I found all `Item` had been added one time after a long wait. why?

how to make those `items` added as my think?

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the GUI thread for too long..
Ideally, you should do PingHost in another thread and inside PingHost, you send a Signal when the result is available. Then you have a SLOT in mainwindow to add the item when the signal is received.

if you insist doing what you are doing now, you could try to update the treeWidget at the end of each loop. See [QWidget::update()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update)

Comment: @midCat, then you're using Signal & SLOT in vain. You still blocked the GUI thread. Try move it to another thread or refresh the treewidget using ui->treeWidget->update();